# Reducing fixed header on scroll from top of page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a website with a fixed header, on the home page the header contains additional content when you are at the top of the page, but I want to hide this content and have a reduced header as they scroll down the page.

So on the initial scroll i want to hide the additional header content and animate the margin of the content below but keep it so that the top of the content still shows underneath it and then scroll from normal from there.

The snippet below should show what I mean better:

```js
var head_height = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
$('#page_content').css('margin-top', (head_height)+'px');

if($('#extra_header_content').length != 0){
    $('#header').addClass('home');
    
    var main_head_height = $("#main_header_content").outerHeight(true);
    var extra_head_height = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
    
    $(document).on("scroll", function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() >= main_head_height){
            $("#extra_header_content").slideUp("slow");
            $('#page_content').css('margin-top', (main_head_height)+'px');
            $('#header').removeClass('home');
        }else{
            $("#extra_header_content").slideDown("slow");
            $('#page_content').css('margin-top', (extra_head_height)+'px');
            $('#header').addClass('home');
        }
    });
}else{
    $('#header').removeClass('home');
}
```

```css
div{padding:0px;margin:0px;}

#header{background-color:#d33;position:fixed;top:0px;width:100%;}
.home{background-color:#3d3 !important;}

#main_header_content{height:50px;width:100%;}
#extra_header_content{height:50px;width:100%;}

#page_content{background-color:#33d;height:5000px;width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div id="main_header_content">Main header</div>
  <div id="extra_header_content">Extra Header</div>
</div>
<div id="page_content">This should still be visible when header initially reduces</div>
```

Comment: are you okay with the small changes in HTML?

Comment: @AtulRajput yeah i'd be ok with some changes, this is just a demo anyway not my actual full html so it probably depends on the changes and how that would work with my actual content

Comment: one more question, do you want the page_content to animate with the hiding header part or a normal jerking effect will work too?

Comment: I'd prefer something nice and smooth at the moment its not great so any improvement would be brilliant

Comment: a very simple metod for you is to use position sticky and not fixed, its quite good like it, I am working on a solution which I will post soon, till then try the sticky solution I am giving below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var head_height = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
$('#page_content').css('margin-top', (head_height)+'px');

if($('#extra_header_content').length != 0){
    $('#header').addClass('home');
    
    var main_head_height = $("#main_header_content").outerHeight(true);
    var extra_head_height = $('#extra_header_content').outerHeight(true);
    
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
        const scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop  >= head_height) {
            $("#extra_header_content").css('height', 0);
            $('#page_content').css('margin-top', main_head_height);
            $('#header').removeClass('home');
        } else if (scrollTop  > 0) {
            $("#extra_header_content").css('height', extra_head_height - scrollTop);
            $('#page_content').css('margin-top', head_height);
            $('#header').removeClass('home');
        } else {
            $("#extra_header_content").css('height', extra_head_height);
            $('#page_content').css('margin-top', head_height);
            $('#header').addClass('home');
        }
    });
}else{
    $('#header').removeClass('home');
}
```

```css
div{padding:0px;margin:0px;}

#header{background-color:#d33;position:fixed;top:0px;width:100%;}
.home{background-color:#3d3 !important;}

#main_header_content{height:100px;width:100%;}
#extra_header_content{height:100px;width:100%; overflow: hidden;}

#page_content{background-color:#33d;height:500px;width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div id="main_header_content">Main header</div>
  <div id="extra_header_content">Extra Header</div>
</div>
<div id="page_content">This should still be visible when header initially reduces</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't work for me as I still need the content to be visible on the initial scroll

Comment: It is visible. I will reduce the height a bit so it's more obvious

Comment: had to change a few things as my minimized snippet doesn't give the full picture but this helped me get there in the end thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to change in your JS code. Margin you are reducing when the page start scrolling need to adjust by padding. So you can try this:

```js
var head_height = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
    $('#page_content').css('margin-top', (head_height)+'px');

    if($('#extra_header_content').length != 0){
        $('#header').addClass('home');
        
        var main_head_height = $("#main_header_content").outerHeight(true);
        var extra_head_height = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
        
        $(document).on("scroll", function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop() >= main_head_height){
                $("#extra_header_content").slideUp("slow");
                // $('#page_content').css('margin-top', (main_head_height)+'px');
                $('#page_content').css(
                  {'margin-top': (main_head_height)+'px', 'padding-top': (main_head_height)+'px'}
                );
                $('#header').removeClass('home');
            }else{
                $("#extra_header_content").slideDown("slow");
                $('#page_content').css('margin-top', (extra_head_height)+'px');
                $('#header').addClass('home');
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#header').removeClass('home');
    }
```

```css
div{padding:0px;margin:0px;}

#header{background-color:#d33;position:fixed;top:0px;width:100%;}
.home{background-color:#3d3 !important;}

#main_header_content{height:50px;width:100%;}
#extra_header_content{height:50px;width:100%;}

#page_content{background-color:#33d;height:5000px;width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div id="main_header_content">Main header</div>
  <div id="extra_header_content">Extra Header</div>
</div>
<div id="page_content">This should still be visible when header initially reduces</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this solution won't work for me as the content has too much of a margin while the extra header is still visible and is not visible when scrolled

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you a different approach without JavaScript

```css
body,html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#main-header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  z-index:3;
}
#extra-header{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 50px;
  background: lime;
  z-index: 0;
}
#content{
  margin-top:100px;
  height:2000px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  background:blue;
}
#content>div{
  height:200px;
  background: #efefef;
}

#content>div:nth-of-type(2n){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-header">
  Main
</div>
<div id="extra-header">
Extra
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution if you will use position sticky and not fixed, but this a bit jerky, So I will post one more solution here with smooth animation

```js
var head_height = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
    //$('#page_content').css('padding-top', (head_height)+'px');

    if ($('#extra_header_content').length != 0) {
        $('#header').addClass('home');

        var main_head_height = $("#main_header_content").outerHeight(true);
        var extra_head_height = $('#header').outerHeight(true);

        $(document).on("scroll", function() {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= main_head_height) {
                $('#page_content').css('padding-top', (main_head_height) + 'px');
                $("#extra_header_content").slideUp("slow");
                //$('.page_content_wrapper').addClass('scrolled');
                //$('.page_content_wrapper').css('top', (main_head_height)+'px');

                $('#header').removeClass('home');
            } else {
                $("#extra_header_content").slideDown("slow");
                $('#page_content').css('padding-top', 0);
                //$('.page_content_wrapper').css('top', 0);
                //$('#header').addClass('home');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#header').removeClass('home');
    }
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    div {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #header {
        background-color: #d33;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9;
    }

    .home {
        background-color: #3d3 !important;
    }

    #main_header_content {
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #extra_header_content {
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #page_content {
        background-color: #33d;
        height: 5000px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .page_content_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;

    }

    #page_content .page_content_wrapper {
        transition: top 1s;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="main_header_content">Main header</div>
        <div id="extra_header_content">Extra Header</div>
    </div>
    <div id="page_content">
        <div class="page_content_wrapper">This should still be visible when header initially reduces</div>
    </div>
    <span class="hamBurger"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately i just used random values for the heights of the headers, my extra header is actually larger than the main header in height so if you change it to `#extra_header_content {height: 150px;}` you'll see it keeps going up and down acouple of times until you scroll past a certain point